# Installing an empty directory with RPM

Tags: directory, installation, rpm, specifications

In my install section of my rpm Spec file I have a bunch of mkdir's to create the directories I need. The ones that don't have any files installed in them get pruned out in the end and don't end up getting created. How can I ensure that the empty directories get created when it is all said and done?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In your %files section:

```
%files
%dir /my/directory/name
```

Comment: m1tk4- will the created directory be removed when the rpm is being uninstalled?

Comment: @OmerDagan Yes.

Answer (score 1):

A complete example of creating an empty directory and setting its permissions.

```
%define _log_dir /var/log/my_package_name

%install
mkdir -p %{buildroot}/%{_log_dir}

%files
%dir %attr(755,owner_name,group_name) %{_log_dir}
```